# IPTables forward from only one ip on my server

Tags: centos, iptables

I was able to get my server to forward connections on a certain port to a different IP, but when I add -d to specify an IP to froward from, It does not work. This is what I am trying,

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 173.208.230.107 -p tcp --dport 80

iptables -t nat -nvL-j DNAT --to-destination 38.105.20.226:80`.
It works fine without the -d. Here is my ifconfig dump:

```
em1       Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:A0:D1:ED:D0:54
          inet addr:173.208.230.106  Bcast:173.208.230.111  Mask:255.255.255.248
          inet6 addr: fe80::2a0:d1ff:feed:d054/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:100058 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:18941701 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
          RX bytes:12779711 (12.1 MiB)  TX bytes:825498499 (787.2 MiB)
          Memory:fbde0000-fbe00000

em1:9     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:A0:D1:ED:D0:54
          inet addr:173.208.230.107  Bcast:173.208.230.111  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:fbde0000-fbe00000

em1:10    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:A0:D1:ED:D0:54
          inet addr:173.208.230.108  Bcast:173.208.230.111  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:fbde0000-fbe00000

em1:11    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:A0:D1:ED:D0:54
          inet addr:173.208.230.109  Bcast:173.208.230.111  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:fbde0000-fbe00000

em1:12    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:A0:D1:ED:D0:54
          inet addr:173.208.230.110  Bcast:173.208.230.111  Mask:255.255.255.248
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          Memory:fbde0000-fbe00000

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 b)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 b)
```

Comment: The proper flag is `--dst`

Comment: @NathanC I place of -d?

Comment: That's right. Should actually work.

Comment: @NathanC When I add that in place of -d, I get bad argument.

Comment: Shouldn't it be just `iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -d 173.208.230.107 -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 38.105.20.226:80`?

Comment: @ott, that did not work either...

Comment: Have you cleaned the old rules before? You need to add `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 173.208.230.248/29 -o em1 -j MASQUERADE` too.

Comment: Still does not work @ott

Answer (score 1):

I believe you only need on rule in the `nat` tables as well as an accept rule.  Add you `-d` or `-dst` to the first rule.

```
iptables -t nat -p 6 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 38.105.20.226
iptables -A INPUT -p 6 --dport 25 -d 38.105.20.226 -j ACCEPT
```